# Yes or No confirmation after checking if data exists in SQL table using javascript

Tags: javascript

The system will check first if the data already exists in SQL table before inserting it. If the data exists,a confirmation message with OK and Cancel will appear. If the user click OK button then the data will be inserted and if the user click Cancel button,the data will not be inserted. Hoping for your help. Thanks!

Comment: Make an `ajax` and in the success make a condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( confirm("Exists data will be replace, are you sure?") ) {
   // insert data
} else {
  // do nothing
}
```

Comment: ,where is the checking of data in the SQL table?

Comment: Javascript itselft cannot query SQL directly (except NodeJS). You have to provide API for it to ajax. Just show your code and ask about the problem directly. do not ask for general idea here.